# How do I draw two squares using the code below that has errors?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *

def drawSquare(sideLength):
    pendown()
    forward(sideLength)
    right(90)
    forward(sideLength)
    right(90)
    forward(sideLength)
    right(90)
    forward(sideLength)
    penup()
def main():
    firstNum= input ("Please enter a number between 10 and 50")
    secondNum= input ("Please enter a multiple of the first number")
    setpos(-10, -10)
    drawSquare(firstNum)
    setpos(50, 50)
    drawSquare(secondNum)
    done()
main()
```

I am trying to draw two different sized squares by inputing side lengths and I keep getting this error: "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" HELPPPPP

Comment: forward expects an int to be passed, however when you capture the input of firstNum and secondNum these are stored as strings. try converting these to ints when you pass them to the func like `drawSquare(int(firstNum))`

Comment: Thanks Chris! It works perfect now!

Comment: Asterisk/`*` imports are discouraged. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score -1):

When you're using Python 3 the default type for input is string, so when you are receiving the input try using int(input("Please enter a number between 10 and 50")), or int(firstNum). Hope this helps!